# Reemplazar los ultimos 3 digitos en 0 JAVA

Tags: java, array, post, bucles, replace

Tengo una pequeña gran consulta, tengo que redondear unos numeros a 000 es decir si es 2.432.123 deberia quedar en 2.432.000  o si es 29.334.123.432 tambien deberia quedar en 29.334.123.000 / sin importar la cantidad de miles de millones, he intentado con varias funciones de JAVA, pero ninguna me ha resultado, no se si tengan una idea de como poder hacerlo, los datos los recibo de un servicio POST.
Intente con replace, con los math de java y nada :C
Si alguien puede iluminarme de como hacerlo, estaría muy agradecido

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo el codigo en javascript pero la idea es la misma seria dividir el valor entre 1000 y convertirlo en int para que de esta forma pierda los decimales y luego multiplicarlo por 1000

```js
var number=22222222222222.11
console.log(22222222222222.11)
console.log(parseInt(number/1000)*1000)
```

```
    double number=2222.11;
    System.out.println(number);

    System.out.println((int)(number/1000)*1000);
```

Comment: La pregunta indica lenguaje Java y esto es JavaScript

Comment: @BetaM la lógica es exactamente la misma lo he puesto en javascript como indico para que le sea mas visual la explicación es funcional para los dos lenguajes

Comment: en teoria la magia esta en (number/1000)*1000) ?? @EnriqueAsensio

Comment: @JuanPablo esto (int)(number/1000)*1000 lo que hace es primero lo divides entre 1000 para pasar la coma la cantidad de decimales que quieres redondear y lo conviertes en (int) que es un tipo de numerico que no admite decimales y automaticamente te lo redondea luego lo multiplicas por 1000 para que vuelvas a tener el mismo numero 
(int)(number/1000)*1000 es lo mismo que 
number =number/1000;
int newNumber = (int)(number)*1000;

Answer (score 0):

según lo que comentaste, quieres evaluar el redondeo para valores muy muy grandes, entonces te recomendaría utilizar BigDecimal. Recordemos que un `double` puede almacenar hasta números de 64 bits, pero si tienes un numero que sobrepasa esta cantidad de bits entonces se recomienda utilizar BigDecimal. Te dejo un ejemplo a continuación:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("29.3342432");

    String number = bd.toPlainString();
    String[] values = number.split("\\.");

    int digitsAfterPoint = values[1].length();
    int digitsToFormat = values[0].length() + (values[1].length() - 3);
    if(digitsAfterPoint <= 3 ){
        digitsToFormat = values[0].length() + 1;
    }

    MathContext mathContext = new MathContext(digitsToFormat);
    bd = bd.round(mathContext);
    number = bd.toPlainString();
    if(number.contains(".")){
        System.out.println(bd + "000");
    }else{
        System.out.println(bd + ".000");
    }
}
```

Básicamente, el algoritmo solo encuentra la cantidad de dígitos que deseas redondear luego del punto flotante y lo redondea.Finalmente, como sabemos los ceros luego del punto flotante no cuentan, entonces si deseas los agregas, en el ejemplo los estoy agregando.

Espero te ayude :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar probar lo siguiente:

```
    public static String formatearMonto(float monto) {
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.00");
    NumberFormat formatNumber = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    formatNumber.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    formatNumber.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    formatNumber.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);
    return format.format(monto);

}

    public static float formatearMontoStringFloat(String monto) {
    String aux = monto.replaceAll(",", "");
    aux = aux.replaceAll(" ", "");
    return Float.parseFloat(aux);

}

public static double formatearMontoStringDouble(String monto) {
    String aux = monto.replaceAll(",", "");
    aux = aux.replaceAll(" ", "");
    return Double.parseDouble(aux);

}
```

Espéro sea de ayuda, saludos!